# Пропал div блок

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Верстал, верстал. И все было не плохо, все отображалось и радовало глаз. НО! В один момент просто перестала отображаться карусель owl. Консоль молчит. Я не менял НИЧЕГО! Обновил страницу после обеда и результат.

```css
.carousel {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 25;
  width: 100%;
}

#owl-carousel .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.owl-carousel:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* display none until init */

.owl-carousel {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  float: left;
}

.owl-controlls .owl-page,
.owl-controlls .owl-buttons {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.owl-controlls {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}


/* mouse grab icon */

.grabbing {
  cursor: url(grabbing.png) 8 8, move;
}


/* fix */

.owl-carousel .owl-wrapper,
.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel">
  <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="carousel_images/banner.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="carousel_images/climate.jpg"></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="carousel_images/refr.jpg"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

В чем причина?

Comment: @entithat ставил block - отображаются все img в столбик. Интуитивно, читая комментарий в цсс, догадываюсь что none только до инициализации. И повторюсь, я ничего не менял. В один прекрасный(нет) момент просто пререстал отображаться.

Comment: Ну расположение  картинок уже не зависит от отображения карусели.

Comment: @entithat да и мой класс только один. Собственно `.carousel{...}` остальное скачаный контент

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился изменением js. Всем спасибо за попытки